# How to enable WS-Security (Rampart) in a Axis2 JAX-WS service (provider side)?

Tags: java, jax-ws, apache-axis, rampart

Is it possible to specify security policy assertions when deploying a JAX-WS service in Axis2? So far I found only one way which is to configure policy globally (i.e. in axis2.xml). But can it be done inside a JAXWS JAR?

Comment: Maybe this will help you. http://www.coderanch.com/t/528485/Web-Services/java/Axis-JAX-WS-Client-Rampart

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow you but it is possible to define a policy in the code. I've posted quite a long answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671162/using-axis2-ramaprt-module-with-own-security-framework/8985123#8985123) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368714/how-to-encrypt-soap-messages-manually/8741600#8741600) which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rampart documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/developer-guide.html),

> All Rampart builders are listed in the META-INF/services/org.apache.neethi.builders.AssertionBuilder file. When adding a new Policy assertion it requires only a builder, assertion model, and an entry in the file.

and it explicitly names a JAR-based location approach which seems to fit with what you're looking for.

Comment: This answer has no relation to the question I asked. I didn't ask how to register Rampart builders, I ask how to register Rampart itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add WS-Policy configuration for a service in the service.xml for the specific service.

The Rampart samples shows how this works, take a look [here](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/samples.html).